# Позиционирование легенды PyQtGraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt, pyqtgraph

Прошу подсказать как позиционируется легенда на графике *PyQtGraph*

```
self.parent.graphicsView3port.addLegend()
self.parent.graphicsView3port.setXRange(0, x, padding=0)      # Границы оси X
self.parent.graphicsView3port.setYRange(0, y, padding=0)   # Границы оси Y
pen = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color=(0, 0, 255), width=2, style=QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
self.parent.graphicsView3port.plot(percent_open_a, flow_list_coeff_a, pen=pen, name="A")
pen = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color=(255, 170, 0), width=2, style=QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
self.parent.graphicsView3port.plot(percent_open_a, flow_list_coeff_b, pen=pen, name="B")
pen = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color=(170, 0, 255), width=2, style=QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
self.parent.graphicsView3port.plot(percent_open_a, flow_list_coeff_ab, pen=pen, name="AB")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу разобраться как сместить легенду ниже. Если добавляю аргумент в addLegend(), то легенда или в левом верхнем углу или в нижнем правом.
Прочитал статью:
https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/plotting-pyqtgraph/
как сделать offset так и не понял. Что куда нужно записать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, ВСЕГДА предоставьте минимально-ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

По умолчанию легенда отображается в левом верхнем углу. 
Если вы хотите переместить его, вы можете легко перетащить легенду
в другое место. 
Вы также **`можете указать смещение`** по умолчанию,
передав 2-кортеж в параметр `offset` при создании легенды.

```
import sys  
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, uic
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        hour = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        temperature = [30, 32, 34, 32, 33, 31, 29, 32, 35, 45]

        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)
        
        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')  
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0), width=3, style=QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature, symbol='o', pen=pen)

        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0), width=3, style=QtCore.Qt.DashLine)

# addLegend  как только вы предоставите pyqtgraph имя для кривой, 
# он сам создаст соответствующий элемент легенды. 
# !!! Однако важно вызывать plt.addLegend() ДО того, как вы создадите кривые.

# -------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <-------------------------
        self.graphWidget.addLegend(offset=(10, 300))
        
        self.graphWidget.plot(
            hour, temperature,                              
            name = "__Legend 1",
            pen=pen, symbol='+', 
            symbolSize=20, symbolBrush=('b')
        )

        self.graphWidget.setTitle(
            "Ваше название здесь",            
            color='7733FF', 
            size='20pt',
            bold=True, 
            italic=True
        )

        self.graphWidget.setLabel(
            'left', 
            "<span style=\"color:red; font-size:20px\">Temperature (°C)</span>")
        self.graphWidget.setLabel(
            'bottom', 
            "<span style=\"color:red; font-size:20px\">Hour (H)</span>")

        self.graphWidget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)  

        self.graphWidget.setXRange(2, 10, padding=0)
        self.graphWidget.setYRange(28, 36, padding=0)        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто не мог понять куда вставлять offset. Если не затруднит, можно ссылку на документацию, которой вы пользуетесь. Где можно подчерпнуть все тонкости, желательно с примерами. До этого в основном на VBA делал необходимые мне вещи. Там с документацией гораздо все проще.

Comment: @ИгорьФедоров пожалуйста. Да я собственно и читал по ссылке, которую вы указали.